# how can i install npm dependencies project?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I'm trying to deploy on my staging server but when i use the npm install command
i have the following problem:

[image: npm install]

and when I try to delete wit `rm -rf node_modules/` i cant'n, i see the following message

```
rm: cannot remove 'node_modules/.html2canvas.DELETE/dist/types/css': Bad message
rm: cannot remove 'node_modules/.caniuse-lite.DELETE/data/features/audiotracks.js': Bad message
```

the proect use node version 10
can someone help me?

Comment: Remove the "node_modules" folder by hand and try it again. Try to run your `rm` command with "sudo"

Comment: with sudo the same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

If you managed to delete the `node_modules/` dir then it should be ok.

However, a `bad message` may indicate sth wrong logically with your filesystem, maybe related to a dirty shutdown, or physically with the disk.

I would recommend you, before you continue using this disk, to do a backup right now, and after you have the backup, a fsck, or if necessary, a disk health check.

Meanwhile, I would recommend you to do the job on another device.

And, right now, unmount the filesystem if possible, prevent any further write to it and other partitions on the same disk (in case it is disk-related), before you have the backup or the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the node_module folder with root access and try to run the installation with `--force` flag.

Comment: ok thx, I'll try it